# How to detect mock location using TrustLocation package in flutter

Tags: flutter, mocking, location, mock-location

I am using trust location package (https://pub.dev/packages/trust_location#-readme-tab-) to detect wether user using fake gps or not...
but the problem is... when I turn on fake gps app.. trust location works fine (await TrustLocation.mockLocation=true) but when I had turned off fake gps app... I still get `await TrustLocation.mockLocation=true`... I need sometime to re-try my app until `await TrustLocation.mockLocation=false`
here is part of my code

```
checkMock() async {
if (await TrustLocation.isMockLocation) {
  print("mock is true")
  }else{
  print("mock is false")
  }
}
```

I call `checkMock()` in an onPress of button
so.. is there a way so that whenever I turn off fake gps app... `TrustLocation.isMockLocation` will directly get `false` value

Comment: This looks like a question to the library's author

Comment: Do you have any idea about how the way to detect wether using fake gps or not?